# Search Nearby Lat/Long Query - Radius search works, but need to add another field

Tags: php, mysql

I have a current location query that works based on a known latitude/longitude.  The search finds matches within a certain radius.

The query is working perfectly, but now I want to add another piece to it.

Let's say I'm searching for `name="Kennedy Middle School"` in `city="Chicago"` AND `state="IL"`

This will yield a x mile radius search.  If the results aren't in the x mile radius of the center of Chicago, IL, the search yields nothing.

I want to include the radius part, but also have another segment of the query that matches on basically:  "`Select FROM WHERE [radius query stuff] OR [city="Chicago and state="IL"]`

I want....."Search for 'Dentist' within a 5 mile radius of x/y point, plus also give me any 'Dentist' where the city is 'Chicago'

This is what my query looks like:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (
 SELECT r.name, r.category, r._address, r.city, r.state, r.lat, r.long, domaintable.domain, 
        MATCH(name, category) AGAINST ('kennedy middle school%') as relevance,
        p.radius,
        p.distance_unit
                 * DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(p.latpoint))
                 * COS(RADIANS(r.lat))
                 * COS(RADIANS(p.longpoint - r.long))
                 + SIN(RADIANS(p.latpoint))
                 * SIN(RADIANS(r.lat)))) AS distance
  FROM nametable_db AS r
  JOIN (   
        SELECT  28.5383355  AS latpoint,  -81.37923649999999 AS longpoint,
                5 AS radius,      69.0 AS distance_unit
    ) AS p
    INNER JOIN domaintable.domain ON
    r.state = domaintable.domain
  WHERE 
    MATCH(name, category) against ('kennedy middle school*' in boolean mode) AND
    r.lat
     BETWEEN p.latpoint  - (p.radius / p.distance_unit)
         AND p.latpoint  + (p.radius / p.distance_unit)
    AND r.long
     BETWEEN p.longpoint - (p.radius / (p.distance_unit * COS(RADIANS(p.latpoint))))
         AND p.longpoint + (p.radius / (p.distance_unit * COS(RADIANS(p.latpoint))))
 ) AS d
 WHERE distance <= radius
 ORDER BY distance
```

Basically, I just want to slip `OR WHERE city="Chicago" and state="IL"` into the query so that the results include this too.

Everyplace I try and edit the query, I end up with it bugging out or not doing anything.

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks.